# Running a Pydev Program with Task Scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, pydev

I am trying to schedule a daily run of a pydev eclipse program that prints the output to a text file. My file is called automated.py, and my command is

```
/c automated.py > logall.txt
```

It starts in C:\Users\cmai\eclipse-workspace\test, which is the location of the file. However, when I run the command, the text file it produces is blank. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it was created on PyDev is probably not relevant to executing it in Python.

Shouldn't your command be something as:

`python automated.py > logall.txt`?